# call store procedure using callproc do not really implement in postgresql?

Tags: python, postgresql, stored-procedures, psycopg2

I have python 3.7 with postgresql:

```
import psycopg2
...
@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add():
    cur = get_db().cursor()
    if request.is_json:
        jdata = request.get_json()
        cur.callproc("add", (jdata['tools'], jdata['ip_begin'], jdata['ip_end']))
        result = cur.fetchall()
        print(result)
        cur.close()
        return jsonify({'result': 'add successful'})
    else:
        cur.close()
        return jsonify({'error':"invalid input json data"})
```

My store function is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION "public"."add"("tool_name" varchar, "ip_bgn" inet, "ip_end" inet) RETURNS "pg_catalog"."int8"
$$  
DECLARE
mid INTEGER := 0;
ins BIGINT := 0;
BEGIN
  if ip_bgn < ip_end then
INSERT into ip_addresses(tool_name, ip_start, ip_end) VALUES (tool_name, ip_bgn, ip_end) RETURNING id into mid;
    Loop
        if ip_bgn + ins >= ip_end then
            exit;
        end if;
        INSERT into ip_pools(tool_name, ip_address, to_main, status) VALUES(tool_name, ip_bgn+ins, mid, 'free');
        ins := ins + 1;
    end Loop;
end if;
RETURN ins;
END $$
```

My output is:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 [(11,)]                   ######################## I have return values
 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Dec/2020 00:37:40] "POST /add HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

but when I go to the database, I find the database does not add any rows after my python code execute.

the database is the same as I execute before.

I can use plpgsql console to create real data via the same store function. But if I run via python code it does not really add rows and change tables, but the return data is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't commit the changes made to the database anywhere. Assuming your connection is defined like this (seems like it is `get_db`, you can change it later):

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="db.host.com", user="username", password="secret")
```

You need to commit the changes after closing the cursor:

```
cur.callproc("add", (jdata['tools'], jdata['ip_begin'], jdata['ip_end']))
# some code
cur.close()
conn.commit()
# close the connection as well once done
conn.close()
```

From [pycopg2 documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html):

> Note that closing a connection without committing the changes first will cause any pending change to be discarded as if a ROLLBACK was performed (unless a different isolation level has been selected: see set_isolation_level()).